# What is wrong with my gradient descent for Polynomial Regresion (C++, GNUPLOT)

Tags: c++, machine-learning, gnuplot

I tried to implement gradient descent for Polynomial regression. I thought i understand everything, but something seems wrong.

[image]

Above is the formula taken from coursera Machine Learning lecutres. 
Now, what about the code:

```
 for(int m=1;m<=degree;m++){
                for(int i = 0;i<iterations;i++)
                   {    
                           getCoefs(learningStep,m);
                   }
                qDebug()<<"Parameters:";
                for(int i=0;i<=degree;i++) {qDebug()<<coefs[i];}

                    switch(m){
                    case 1:  equation = to_string(coefs[1]) + "*x+" + to_string(coefs[0]);
                             g1.set_style("lines").plot_equation(equation,"x^1"); break;
                    case 2:  equation = to_string(coefs[2])+ "*x**2+" + to_string(coefs[1]) + "*x+" + to_string(coefs[0]);
                             g1.set_style("lines").plot_equation(equation,"x^2"); break;
                    case 3:  equation = to_string(coefs[3])+ "*x**3+" +to_string(coefs[2])+ "*x**2+" + to_string(coefs[1]) + "*x+" + to_string(coefs[0]);
                             g1.set_style("lines").plot_equation(equation,"x^3"); break;
                    case 4:  equation = to_string(coefs[4])+ "*x**4+" + to_string(coefs[3])+ "*x**3+" +to_string(coefs[2])+ "*x**2+" + to_string(coefs[1]) + "*x+" + to_string(coefs[0]);
                             g1.set_style("lines").plot_equation(equation,"x^4"); break;
                    case 5:  equation = to_string(coefs[5])+ "*x**5+" + to_string(coefs[4])+ "*x**4+" + to_string(coefs[3])+ "*x**3+" +to_string(coefs[2])+ "*x**2+" + to_string(coefs[1]) + "*x+" + to_string(coefs[0]);
                             g1.set_style("lines").plot_equation(equation,"x^5"); break;
                    }

                for(int i=0;i<=degree;i++) {coefs[i]=0;}
              }
```

It is the function for plotting the equations. 
**Coefs** is a vector for parameters {ø1,ø2...øn}

**degree** Is an int number of the biggest degree i want to calculate.

**iterations** number of steps, in my case 2000

**learningStep** no need to explain (0.001 [I tried as well bigger LS 0.01 but the result was also wrong])

```
void getCoefs(double learningStep, int degree){
QVector < double > sum;
for(int j=0;j<=degree;j++){
    sum.push_back(0);
 }

double numberOfPoints = point.length();
QVector < double > actual;
for(int j=0;j<=degree;j++){
    actual.push_back(coefs[j]);
 }

for(int i=0;i<point.length();i++){

    for(int j=0;j<=degree;j++){
        sum[j] += (1/numberOfPoints) *(((actual[1]*point[i].getX() + actual[0]) - (point[i].getY()))*pow(point[i].getX(), j));
    }
}
for(int j=0;j<=degree;j++){

    coefs[j] -= learningStep*sum[j];
}
```

}

Here is my code for getting coefs. 
**point** is a vector of points (Objects with two variables x,y).

**actual** is a vector containing coefs for our hypothesis function.

Here we calculate the sum showed on the picture one:

> sum[j] += (1/numberOfPoints) *(((actual[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VJO0V.jpg)*point[i].getX() + actual[0]) - (point[i].getY()))*pow(point[i].getX(), j));

And here we are changing each ø.

> coefs[j] -= learningStep*sum[j];

I thought everything is done as it supposed to be. It worked fine for linear regression, but it is not working for polynimial regression.

[image]
We can see here easily that x^1 fits perfectly, but the other functions are fitted only to the middle points. It looks more clearly on the next picture:
[image]

I would love to understand it, but i simply have no idea what is wrong. mathematically everything is correct (Or maybe i missed something)

**EDIT**
I changed the hypothesis and it worked like a charm!
[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You misunderstand polynomial regression. Hypothesis should look like

[image]

Where `theta`s are parameters that you're trying to learn. Note that there are `m+1` completely independent variables.

Even though your `coefs` is indeed of size `m+1`, `coefs[2], ..., coefs[m]` are never used. In fact, you always use linear model:

```
actual[1]*point[i].getX() + actual[0]
```

computes

[image]

You should replace aforementioned code with one that computes higher-order polynomial.

Comment: That was the problem! Thank you very much Barmaley.exe!